# triple integration of $\begin{aligned} f_{X, Y,Z}(x, y, z) &=\frac{2}{\pi} e^{x(y+z-x-4)-\frac{1}{2}\left(y^{2}+z^{2}\right)}\end{aligned}$

Tags: integration

The question is:
I need to get

$f_{x, y}(x, y)$

from

$\begin{aligned} f_{X, Y,Z}(x, y, z) &=\frac{2}{\pi} e^{x(y+z-x-4)-\frac{1}{2}\left(y^{2}+z^{2}\right)}\end{aligned}$

This is my process

$\begin{aligned} f_{X, Y}, z(x, y, z) &=\frac{2}{\pi} e^{x(y+z-x-4)-\frac{1}{2}\left(y^{2}+z^{2}\right)} \\ f_{X,} y(x, y) &=\frac{2}{\pi} \int e^{x(y+z-4)-\frac{1}{2}\left(y^{2}+z^{2}\right)} d z \\ &=\frac{2}{\pi} e^{x(y-x-4)-\frac{1}{2} y^{2}} \int e^{x z-\frac{1}{2} z^{2}} d z \end{aligned}$

I've been using the partial integral for the last part, but it doesn't work..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have written $$\int\frac{2}{\pi}e^{x(y+z-x-4) - \frac{1}{2}(y^2 + z^2)}dz = \frac{2}{\pi}e^{x(y-x-4) - \frac{1}{2}y^2}\int e^{xz-\frac{1}{2}z^2}dz.$$ Then $$\int e^{xz-\frac{1}{2}z^2}dz = \int e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2 + xz - \frac{1}{2}z^2 + \frac{1}{2}x^2}dz = e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}\int e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-z)^2}dz.$$ Let $u = x-z$ so $du = -dz$. Then the last integral becomes $$\int -e^{-\frac{1}{2}u^2}du = -\int e^{-\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2}du = -\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{2}}\right) + C =  -\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{x-z}{\sqrt{2}}\right) + C.$$
I will leave it to you to combine all the simplifications together. If you are not familiar with the error function you can see the definition here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function.

Comment: That is a definite integral. What's with $x$ and $z$?

Comment: So the error function is defined as $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{erf}(y) = \int_0^y e^{-t^2}dt$. Then $\frac{d}{dy}\left( \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{erf}(y)\right) = e^{-y^2}$. This means that $$\int e^{-y^2}dy =  \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{erf}(y) + C.$$ And for us $y = u/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: No the integral stands for $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dz$. That is how you obtain a marginal distribution from the full probability distribution. The answer cannot depend on $z$, as it is clear from the formulation of the problem. So the steps are correct until the last one which is wrong.

Comment: No, erf is just shorthand. It still stands for the integral and there is no issue. See this paper
https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73b/jresv73bn1p1_a1b.pdf.
At the bottom of page 3, $$\mathrm{erf}\left(az + \frac{w}{a}\right) = \frac{2a}{\sqrt{\pi}}\exp\left(c - \frac{w^2}{a^2}\right)\int e^{-(a^2z^2 + 2wz + c)}dz .$$

Comment: @lcv Also see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1530268/integral-of-e-x2-and-the-error-function

Comment: I mean no disrespect (it's easy to get carried away online). But look at the OP's question. The answer is supposed to be a function of $x$ and $y$ alone, while yours is a function of $z$ too, how do you explain that? PS I'm familiar with the error function